# customise status code for each failed rule like custom message

Tags: laravel, api, rest, validation, http-status-codes

My need is I need to return custom status code for api request. Status code for all validation might not be same for all the rule so i want to add status code for each validation fail just like in request file we can simply add message function and edit error message for each validation failed for each rule.

so is there a way or Laravel already has a feature where i can edit status code for validation fail just like message?

Comment: Use this `return response()->json("response content", 202);` or `return response()->json(['message' => 'this is a message'],202);`

Comment: Is all your validation made as form request validation ? How would a message look like? (example)